# Add spaces to a string to be used in .HTMLBody

Tags: html, excel, vba, string

I've tried several ways including making another string that acts as a space, and also "    ".

```
StrBody2 = "<b>Downtime particulars</b>" & "<br>" & _
           "Short description: " & space(10) & _
           Range("External_Start_Description").Text & "<br>" & "<br>"
```

I want a space between "Short description" and Range("External_Start_Description").Text.

I expect this has to do with using the range function in the string.

Context: this string is later used in an email with other strings:

```vb
.HTMLBody = "<p><font color=""#112369"" face=""arial"" size=""10px"">" & StrBody & StrBody2 & RangetoHTML(rng) & StrBody3
```

Comment: `"Short description: "  & Range("External_Start_Description").Text &` this should do it.

Comment: I wonder why you think it doesn't work? I've tested your code and works fine on my end, what are you doing with that variable? And... try Debug.Print, might help.

Comment: Added context to the original question

Comment: `Replace(space(10), " ", "&nbsp;")`

Comment: Wouldn't need to replace, just to use that instead of the space... `"Short description: " & "&nbsp" & Range("test_name").Text & "<br>" & "<br>"`

Comment: @DarXyde That's just 1 space though

Comment: @TimWilliams, true, but I think that's all he tried to achieve... Space(10) was most likely an exagerated trial to be more obvious is working or not.

Answer (score 4):

HTML collapses runs of multiple spaces to a single space - you need to use the non-breaking space entity `&nbsp;` if you want a run of spaces.

```
Replace(space(10), " ", "&nbsp;")
```

Comment: You mean Replace("stringToApplyTheReplaceTo", "FindAsString", "ReplaceAsString")...

Comment: I meant what I wrote?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realise at first why this suggestion. Pretty neat hack for adding an infinite number of `&nbsp;` ... I`ll keep this in mind for similar applications.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is put quotes with a space in your concatenation like below:

```
StrBody2 = "<b>Downtime particulars</b>" & "<br>" & _
           "Short description: " & " " & Range("External_Start_Description").Text & "<br>" & "<br>"
```

Comment: I've tried that and that doesn't work, adding more context in the original post now